# Mongo query from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

I am inserting weatherdata from `openweathermap` using ASP.Net. Insertion is working fine. When I am trying to query from the application I am trying to retrieve data from the document where `weatherinfo.sys.country="Australia"` and `weatherinfo.name="Sydney"`.

```
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("weatherdb");
using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
{
    IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("weatherinfo.sys.country", "Australia"),   Query.EQ("weatherinfo.name", "Sydney"));

    Response.Write(query);
    var results = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("weatherdatanew13").Find(query);
    Response.Write(results);
}
```

But, I am not getting the expected results.

Comment: MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]    am getting this response when am printing it.

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting? I mean do you want to map it to objects, or BsonDocument is fine for you?

Comment: @user3600372 Can you share your solution as an answer? ;).